# VBA code to add password to current workbook not working

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to use a line of VBA code to add password to my current open workbook, but after I ran that, then closed and reopened the same file, it did not require the password I added. Can anyone please help me understand why? Thanks in advance!

```
Sub addPassword()
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Password:="qq1234"
End Sub
```

Comment: Has your workbook been saved already when calling this code?

Comment: @Ike, I tried both saving and not saving before running the macro, but neither saved the file with my password.

Comment: Maybe adding the fullfilename to the call helps. For me it worked ...

Comment: @Ike Thank you too! I tried using the full file name and then it was able to add the password, it would not save the changes I made on the sheet though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub SaveWithPassword()
 Dim fileF As Long
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ActiveWorkbook
        fileF = .FileFormat
        .SaveAs Filename:=.FullName, FileFormat:=fileF, Password:="qq1234", CreateBackup:=False
       .Close False
    End With
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Even if all `SaveAs` method parameters are `Optional`, there are some things which Excel cannot always guess.

`ThisWorkbook` does not mean the active book, except the case when the workbook keeping the code is the active one. The default `FileFormat` is the last one used. If it does not matches with the workbook one, Excel is not able to save it.

The above way uses minimum of the necessary parameters and it should not fail...

Comment: @qiao Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: I tested and it was successful! Can you tell me why my previous code would not work? many thanks!

Comment: @qiao I tried explaining in the question... Besides that, if you save a workbook in the same location, it will overwrite the existing. Sometimes, it asks for permission, other times it does not. Without `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` it cannot save if over the existing. Not using the appropriate `FileFormat`, Excel may even crush. If not supplied, it try using the last one used before. That's why is it good to use all the necessary parameters, to be sure that everything will be clear regarding your intention... Otherwise, Excel tries guessing, but not all the time it is able to do it...